# Syntax to show only few values form a field

Tags: validation, validation-rule

There is a field called Job title on a custom object which while creating that custom object automatically fills the concatenation name of Account and Job field as a result I can see Account Name + Job =AccountNameJob on Job title.

eg: Job field has Dell-Recruiter value I want to show only Recruiter as a value

I want to show this on the report related to custom object.

How shall I accomplish this task?

Comment: So, the user enters in "Recruiter", and something adds the account name to the same field. But the original job value is never preserved anywhere?

Comment: Are you using trigger for concatenation ?

Comment: No it is coming by default as it is a purchased application.Further i saw the LEN.Right Formulaes which can be used.Is it possible to use them?